# Identify a button click on list view android

Tags: java, android, listview, position, buttonclick

I have created a `ListView` using a custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>`. I need to add the item name to an `ArrayList` when it clicks on the `+` button.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly as usual (like in `MainActivity`), just link it in `GetView(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **ArrayAdapter.java** , add this:

```
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        void onAddClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

Inside your **Holder** Function on same file, make this:

```
    AddButtonVariable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(listener != null)
            {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(position != ListView.NO_POSITION)
                {
                    listener.onAddClick(position);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Inside in your **onResponse** function of *Activity.java* file add this, after setAdapter:

```
listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ArrayAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAddClick(int position){           
            functiontoAdd(String.valueOf(position));
    }
});
```

Now, at last, inside your **Activity.Java** file, at the end (*before closing bracket of class*), add this:

```
private void functiontoAdd(String position)
{
    // rest of the code to add item in cart
}
```

Look, it is simpler with using Recycler view instead of list view. But it is ok if you already created.

Answer (score 0):

```java
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                long id) 
          {
        //I am assuming the ArrayAdapter is having list of dish name as string if the list is of Custom class please change the below code as per it.
                String dish = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
    
          }
       });
```

**adapter** *AdapterView*: The AdapterView where the click happened.

**view**    *View*: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

**position**    *int*: The position of the view in the adapter.

**id**  *long*: The row id of the item that was clicked.